# how to get values in discrete ranges from a DB table , using SQL Queries

Tags: mysql

Assume a DB table with values

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]
```

Note: this pattern is not necessary (the sorted order and values from 1-30).

so using a query I can get values between 10-20 and so on.

But here I want to  know how I can get values from different ranges.
i.e:

- one random value from range 0-5
- one value form range 6-10
- one value from range 11-15
- one value from range 16-20

... so on.

So the output of the query will  looks like:

```
[2,7,14,16,23,29,...]
```

or

```
[1,6,11,18,22,26,...]
```

Is there any way I can achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Try for this

```
(SELECT id as r1 FROM `t1` WHERE id between 1 and 5 ORDER BY RAND() limit 0,1)

 union 

(SELECT id as r1 FROM `t1` WHERE id between 6 and 10 order by RAND() limit 0,1)

 union 

(SELECT id as r1 FROM `t1` WHERE id between 11 and 15 order by RAND() limit 0,1)

 union 

 (SELECT id as r1 FROM `t1` WHERE id between 16 and 20 order by RAND() limit 0,1)

union 

(SELECT id as r1 FROM `t1` WHERE id between 21 and 25 order by RAND() limit 0,1)

union 

(SELECT id as r1 FROM `t1` WHERE id between 26 and 30 order by RAND() limit 0,1)
```

This the query of specified rang if you want make it for dynamically range you need make this query dynamically once you have all the range up to N.